# Is it possible to execute a command automatically upon launch in R?

Tags: r

I use R from the GUI app (R.app). When I open the app, it loads some data (e.g. `.Rapp.history` or `.RData`) from the working directory. However, is it possible to execute some commands or functions automatically upon launch?

I just want to load some libraries such as `ggplot2` or `plyr`, which I always use on my session.

Comment: Yes you can. Are you using console or Rstudio?

Comment: @naltipar I use GUI `R.app`, which I installed from the official website. I don't use RStudio nor run from Terminal.

Comment: Careful with it though. I added package loading to my Rprofile and ended taking them all out after having so much trouble with package updates, removing packages, devel version installs, package masking, ...

Comment: Pierre; just what i was going to say... it creates problems with some package installs, and importantly also reduces script portability / clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit your `Rprofile.site` and add the desired commands to the functions `.Last` and `.First` respectively.

More info about Rprofile.site: [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html)

> At startup, R will source the Rprofile.site file. It will then look for a .Rprofile file to source in the current working directory. If it doesn't find it, it will look for one in the user's home directory. There are two special functions you can place in these files. .First( ) will be run at the start of the R session and .Last( ) will be run at the end of the session.

That said, you can edit the function `.First()` to load the desired libraries.

```
.First <- function() {
  library("dplyr")
  library("ggplot2")
}
```

You can edit the same file and this command, which is used specifically for this purpose:

```
options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"),
   "dplyr","ggplot2"))
```

Comment: `getOption('defaultPackages')` is specifically for this

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm. Which file do you recommend to use?

Comment: @rawr you are right, but I rarely use that command and it didn't occur to me. @Blaszard I'd say `Rprofile.site` which is universal. `.Rprofile` is better used when you have many workspaces and you'd like to have custom commands for each one.